# Can I grab the current template within the javascript console?

Tags: javascript, meteor

if you have an `onRendered` callback, you can log the `this` to get the template.

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function () {
  console.log(this);
});
```

For debugging purposes, in the javascript console, is it possible to get the current rendered template via some sort of script? Eg:

```
> var ctx = Template.myTemplate  // something like this
```

Comment: Adding to the answers below, you also have the dirty solution: `debugger;`! It tells the debugger to stop the execution at this point (yes, it's some kind of sad breakpoint), you can then inspect the scope as much as you like.

Comment: yeah that is one solution, but tbh it is quite a bit slower, especially when I just want to confirm data is correct on each route

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Chrome (and possibly other browsers), after you `console.log` an object, you can right click on the output in the JavaScript console and click "Store as global variable". That will assign it to a variable (named `temp1`, `temp2`, and so on). You can then access that object through the new variable.

---

Also in Chrome, selecting an element in the developer tools makes it available in the JavaScript console as `$0`. If you define the following function globally:

```
getTemplateInstance = function (elem) {
  var view = Blaze.getView(elem);
  while (!view.templateInstance) {
    view = view.parentView;
  }
  return view.templateInstance();
}
```

Then you can get any rendered template instance by following these steps:

1. Right click somewhere on the template
2. Click "Inspect element"
3. In the developer tools, switch to the JavaScript console
4. Enter `getTemplateInstance($0)` to get the template instance.

If you're careful to only select an element at the top level of the template (not inside a `{{#if}}`, `{{#each}}`, etc.) then you can skip the `getTemplateInstance` function and just run `Blaze.getView($0).templateInstance()` in the console.

You can also use `Blaze.getData($0)` to get the data context of an element.

Comment: this is a lot of very helpful information! Thank you so much good sir

Answer (score 3):

Because its possible to have two of the same template you have explicitly pass on its reference to a global variable.

```
ctx = null;

Template.myTemplate.onRendered(function () {
    ctx = this;
});
```

This should let you use 'ctx' anywhere. It depends a lot on where you use it,  you can get the template instance in events or helpers you can get the template instance from within its own helpers or events:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
    'click #something': function(e,tmpl) {
         console.log(tmpl) //The template instance
         console.log(Template.instance())  //just like tmpl
     }
});

Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    'somehelper': function() {
         console.log(Template.instance());
     }
});
```

Comment: Global variables works only in non-strict mode, do not use with 'use strict'.